# how to remove extra spaces from string in python

Tags: python, json, string, api, response

```
{'\[\\n M a k i n g   c o f f e e   i s   n o t   r e l a t e d   t o   t h e   c o n t e x t   i n f o r m a t i o n   p r o v i d e d .\]'}
```

I need this response as below:

```
Making coffee is not related to the context information provided.
```

I have tried as below:

```
import re
import json
import string
import re

my_int ={'\[\\n M a k i n g   c o f f e e   i s   n o t   r e l a t e d   t o   t h e   c o n t e x t   i n f o r m a t i o n   p r o v i d e d .\]'}
a=\[\]
print(type(my_int))
result = re.sub(r'\[0-9\]', '\_', str(my_int))

print(type(result))
print(" ".join(result.split()))
print(result.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace}))

print(re.sub(r"\\s+", "", result), sep='')
print(re.sub(r"^\\s+", "", result), sep='')
print(re.sub(r"\\s+$", "", result), sep='')
print(re.sub(r"^\\s+|\\s+$", "", result), sep='')`
```

Tried all these ways to get the result but there is no success.

NOTE: Here as you see all the letters are separate characters, hence i am not able to remove the spaces between them.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `my_int[::2]` or `my_int[1::2]` to get the odd or even characters respectively

Comment: You can use an alternate char.
```re.sub("\|", " ", re.sub(r" ", "", re.sub("  ", "|", result)))```

Comment: @apapillon great that worked, can you also help me on how to only take out these strings without any special character for example : Making coffee is not related to the context information provided.

Answer (score 2):

#### What a horrible input!

Someone has created for you a set, for no reason.

Inside it they have put a single element, and that is not a string but an ugly way of putting a string in side `[` and `]` characters.

You can extract it, though. A fudge for the spaces is to temporarily convert the double spaces into something else, remove all the other spaces, and then bring back the double spaces. Just make sure that the sequence you use, such as `!DOUBLESPACE!` cannot occur in your string. You might want to use international characters that are not used in your region of the world.

```
my_set ={'\[\\n M a k i n g   c o f f e e   i s   n o t   r e l a t e d   t o   t h e   c o n t e x t   i n f o r m a t i o n   p r o v i d e d .\]'}

my_string = list(my_set)[0].replace("\[","").replace("\]","").replace("\\n","").replace("  ","!DOUBLESPACE!").replace(" ","").replace("!DOUBLESPACE!"," ")

print(my_string)
```

No `import`s are needed.

Result:

```
Making coffee is not related to the context information provided.
```

#### Type of result

You definitely do not want a `set` result. Someone has given you a set as an input.

The result of the above code, `my_string`, is just a string. Make sure to use that, and not the set, for onward processing.

Comment: Thanks it worked when i try to use just this part , but while running in azure function locally via vs code getting error : Exception: TypeError: response is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got set

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re

my_int = {'\[\\n M a k i n g   c o f f e e   i s   n o t   r e l a t e d   t o   t h e   c o n t e x t   i n f o r m a t i o n   p r o v i d e d .\]'}

for s in my_int:
    s = re.sub(r'\\.', '', s)
    s = re.sub(r'\s(?=\S)|(?<=\S)\s', '', s)
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Making coffee is not related to the context information provided.
```